# C var definition, char limit is bytes or bits?

Tags: c, char

```
 char name [Number];
```

[Number] is bytes or bits?

Comment: Well name is an array of chars. number denotes the number of chars in the array. Thus the array has a total size reserved for 10 chars.

Comment: That is much the same in any common programming language. Why don't you just pick a C book and learn the language properly? Asking particular questions about such basic subjects will not give the whole picture you need.

Comment: @Olaf: not quite in any common programming language, but certainly in most of those that use a C-like syntax.

Comment: Yes it will. while working purely with js sometimes work requires: Hey! Look at a sketch of what you are doing in C++, here is another in php, oh look there is something you can use from C#, oh look another bit of what you may need is in .sh
I would love to properly learn all that, but time is not on my side for the proyects im assigned. So it´s better to just ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP couldn't be bothered to read a book about the language s/he was asking about

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: There are other languages, too which use a similar syntax. And most PLs use brackets to index elements in an array. It really can be deduced with a little thought. If not, there is much more missing about C (or programming in general), so an answer to this particular problem will have to be more of a tutorial already.

Comment: @KarmaDoe: " but time is not on my side for the proyects im assigned. So it´s better to just ask." - No. Because you will miss the relevant parts and cannot be productive. Bad for the company and for the project (and for you).

Comment: Yes, brackets to index, but the number of elements is not necessarily indicated this way. Pascal-like languages often use a range, e.g. `array[1..100] of Char`.

Comment: I´m sure the question is not unclear. In fact, it was easily answered by many. What im not sure about is, why so rude? 
Can´t posibly read books of all the languages just to work with one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: IIRC, it is only Pascal and Ada. Wirth finally dropped support for arbitrary ranges with Modula (Ada is not his language), Oberon the same. Anyway, it can be expected from a programmer to find out such simple things himself - eof-.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. None of you understood, the question was:
Characters, bytes or bits.

Comment: @Olaf: He is building up [technical debt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: @KarmaDoe: this could easily be found in any textbook about C. It is better to learn for yourself than to ask such basic questions. `Number` denotes the number of elements, in this case chars.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between `char` and bytes in C?

Comment: I dont have any textbooks nearby, just needed to read 50 lines of code in a foreign language to get an idea of what needed to be done. Wanted to clarify the only doubt i had by asking here. But no, i guess help is better sought elsewhere.

Comment: And you are apparently not online, too ... If you often ask others to do your job, you won't make much friends in your co-workers ...

Comment: @KarmaDoe: you don't have to read about all languages. But you asked about C (see tag), so you could read a basic tutorial about C. How else do you plan to finish even the simplest project?

Comment: @Olaf ([Char, Bytes] || [Bits])

Comment: @KarmaDoe: people understood that, but wondered why you could not find out for yourself. People here expect you to help yourself first, and only to ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Let´s debate why can't you be bothered with such simple questions, for longer than it would take just to ignore it or answer.
Brilliant idea chap!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Thanks for the link. Didn't know there is a term for what my customers want and I try to avoid. Maybe I get some arguments the non-programmers better understand. (Although I somewhat doubt they are open to logical arguments anyway)

Comment: If you want others to spend their precious time to help you, it makes sense not to be offensive and to show you value their help by showing the effort you already took youself. Your attitude doesn't help.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I did look it up. It said: [Number] is the limit of the array.
Needed to clarify some more, so the question was posted.

Comment: Then you did not look very thoroughly.

Comment: You have obviously never read a "How to make friends" tutorial. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis This is not a getFriends site, thought this was:
Ask code related questions, get code related answers site.
My bad. I should befriend all the rude and more experienced C programmers now.
Thanks for making me notice my mistakes and missconceptions.

Comment: I never said so. But being polite and showing some effort to help youself motivates people to help you. Your attitude does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number specifies the number of elements in the array.

We can do:

```
char name[10];
```

To allocate 10 bytes, or something like:

```
#define Number 10

char name[Number];
```

This means you can store up to 10 characters, although the \0 sequence marks the end of a string - this tells other string handling functions where the end of the string is.

So techinally we can store 9 characters and the \0 to terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

In general,

```
typename variablename[length];
```

declares an array called `variablename` of `length` number of `typename` instances.

```
char name[100];
```

An array called `name` of 10 `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, it is the number of elements your array of character will have.

For example:

```
char name[10]; // name can be 10 characters length at most.
```

Answer (score 0):

"Number" is how many elements (of type char) the array "name" contain.

In this case, the size of the array will be exactly "Number", because a char variable is sized 1 byte.

Remember that an array of char (also called string) has to have a nul (not NULL) character ('\0', the first character in the ASCII table) at the end to be correctly readable.